# No puedo acceder a la página de GitHub

Tags: github, internet

Al intentar entrar a github me aparece esto.

[image: Error en Edge]

Intenté usar ping en el cmd y me dice que no encuentra la página tampoco. Es como si no existiera.

Siguiendo una guia, cambié el DNS de las propiedades de ethernet por las de google.

[image: Ethernet]

**Se que esto no tiene nada de código, pero quizá alguien pueda ayudarme**

Answer (score 0):

Las [DNS de Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns) son 8.8.8.8 y 8.8.4.4. Es decir, escribiste al revés el servidor secundario.

Quizá sea por eso que no encuentra la página.

Comment: Hola! Lo corregí, reinicié y sigue exactamente el mismo problema.

Comment: @Iván y con los DNS por defecto? Desde otros dispositivos también tienes el problema?

Comment: Creo que tiene que ser un problema relacionado con el Modem y el cable de Red. Con mi teléfono y otra pc que esta con Wifi si puedo acceder.

Anteriormente no tenía este problema pero hace una semana formatee la pc y ahora no puedo

Comment: @Iván de casualidad agregaste alguna regla para bloquear el sitio? Podría ser eso también. Por cierto, no olvides activar la casilla de **Validar información al salir** para saber que la configuración está bien.

Comment: Yo no bloquee nada. Sin embargo, es posible que algo lo haya hecho? Justamente ayer se me metió un troyano, no se si habrá interferido en algo. Donde podría ver lo de el bloqueo?

Comment: Quizá. No soy experto, pero puedes revisar el archivo [hosts](https://www.adslzone.net/esenciales/windows-10/editar-archivo-host/) y las reglas del firewall. En el último caso debes ir a la configuración avanzada del firewall para verlas. Como último recurso puedes formatear de nuevo y ten cuidado con lo que descargas

Answer (score 0):

yo tengo el mismo problema para acceder a la pagina de Github desde mi Laptop, pero creo que debe ser algo de la configuración de red en el equipo, porque me instalé el opera para unas pruebas del vpn y ya pude entrar.

saludos.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/406398)